# php - unable to read unique id for multiple checkbox with single button

Tags: php, mysql

i try to insert data using checkbox and it works. but when i changed it to a single button for the multiple checkbox, it cannot detect each product that i've checked

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product LIMIT $start, $per_page");

while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)):
?>                                              
<li class="span3">
<div class="product-box">
<span class="sale_tag"></span>
<?php echo '<p><a href="product_det.php?id='.$data['code'].'"><img src="admin/pro_image/'.$data['image'].'" /></a></p>'; ?>
<?php echo '<a href="product_det.php?id='.$data['code'].'" class="title">'.$data['name_nl'].'</a>'; ?>
<br/>                                           
<td><input class='addon' type='checkbox' name='add[]' a href='cart.php?add='.$data['code'].''></td>
<p class="price"><?php echo 'RM '.$data['price']; ?></p>
</div>
</li>

<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>   
<?php echo '<a href="cart.php?add='.$data['code'].'"><button> Add to Cart </button></a>'; ?>
```

btw, "code" is unique id for product..

this is my code for insert into cart:

```
if(isset($_GET['add'])){
$id = $_GET['add'];
$qt = mysql_query("SELECT code, quantity FROM product WHERE code='$id'");
while($qt_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qt)){
if($qt_row['quantity'] != $_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['add']] && 
$qt_row['quantity'] > 0){
    $_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['add']]+='1';
    header("Location: cart.php");
} else {
    echo '<script language="javascript">alert("Not Enough Stock!"); 
document.location="index.php";</script>';
}
}
```

Comment: Concatenation can be tricky in php. Take a better look at your code and focus on when the problem appeared. *When you added everything to be executed with the click of a single submit box*. You're on the right path

Comment: `<td><input class='addon' type='checkbox' name='add[]' a href='cart.php?add='.$data['code'].''></td>` this line is wrong... missing end of input tag (or wrong attribute href which tag input don't support), missing start and close tag for a, `$data['code']` is php thing when php don't process it... also on last line `$data` reference to last row from db. checkboxes work only with forms or javascript both missing

Comment: i try to change it to 
<input type='checkbox' name='add[]' value='<?php echo '.$data['code'].';?>'>
but i get this kind of error:
syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'
and i dont know how to fix it..